# C# Sending a JSON object with a list to WebAPI is coming up null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman, insomnia

I have a class object that contains a list of user emails.

```
public class UserAccount
{
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  public List<string> UserEmails {get; set;}
}
```

When passing a json object in Insomnia to my web api post method. The username is populated but the UserEmails is null.

```
{
  "UserAccount":
  {
     "UserName": "StackOverflow",
     "UserEmails":[
    "abc@asd.com",
    "xyz@asd.com"
    ]
  }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> DoUserStuff([FromBody] UserAccount account)
{
  // account.UserName is populated
 //  account.UserEmails are null
}
```

What am I missing with the JSON payload?

Comment: You at least have a typo in your class definition. I'm assuming it is in fact a class?

Comment: shouldn't be public class UserAccount?

Comment: @DavidL yes it was I forgot to add the word class. I have fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your classes should be

```
     public class Data
    {
        public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserAccount
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public List<string> UserEmails { get; set; }
    }
```

and action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DoUserStuff([FromBody] Data data)
```